# InfluxDB reports "unauthorized access" with the generated token

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I downloaded the latest version of InfluxDB, it's influxdb2-2.0.3_darwin_amd64. I want to write data to the InfluxDB, and followed the documentation of "[Use InfluxDB API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/write-data/developer-tools/api/)". I got the "unauthorized access" message.

```
 curl --request POST "http://localhost:8086/api/v2/write?org=9682c3eaabb5384c&bucket=test_bucket&precision=s" \
 --header "Authorizations: TOKEN _XHOou59351P2Y8JjVDRWNMN22phTUzDVpUJtN85Dby6rfKSjDmGnxWTS_CbjZj-TJn7EaEduDwgtQyOY3BUeg==" \
 --data-raw "mem,host=host1 used_percent=23.43234543 1556896326"

{"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"}
```

The token was copied from the web UI.
[image]

Could anyone help me to solve this authentication problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't follow the documentation exactly, it's case sensitive. It's "Token", not "TOKEN".

```
--header "Authorization: Token YOURAUTHTOKEN"
```

Comment: exactly. Must be capital T. Beware, some proxy might change all headers to lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
`curl --request POST  http://localhost:8086/api/v2/query?org=yourOrgName --header 'Authorization: Token tokenValue' --header 'Accept: application/csv' --header 'Content-type: application/vnd.flux' --data 'from(bucket:"BucketName") |> range(start: 0)|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "MeasurementName")'`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).